# how to download image in background to set with imageView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

i have used following code but doesn't worked for me.

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(markerView.bounds.size.width/10, markerView.bounds.size.height/4, markerView.bounds.size.width*4/5, markerView.bounds.size.height/1.5)];

NSString *strPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrTemp valueForKey:@"image"] objectAtIndex:marker.accessibilityLabel.integerValue]];
NSLog(@"img path %@", strPath);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strPath]]];
  imgView.image = img;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try code below.
its worked for me.

```
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[dictTemp valueForKey:@"image"] objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"imagepath"]];
        NSString *strSub = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
        NSURL *imgUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strSub]];

        dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(q, ^{
            /* Fetch the image from the server... */
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl];
            UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [imageView setImage:img];
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

add the `SDWebImage` folder in your project then select following option. To add copy of your folder to the destination project and Create groups.

and then call header as like

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

And make sure that you are adding to all the targets that you want to use that library.

[image]

Documentation at [Github](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) :

Add the SDWebImage project to your project

- Download and unzip the last version of the framework from the download page
- Right-click on the project navigator and select "Add Files to "Your Project":
- In the dialog, select SDWebImage.framework:
- Check the "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" checkbox

Or you can use `cocoa pods` as other answer suggested.

finally called like

```
[imgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strPath] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try DispatchQueue.async (xcode 8.0+):

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.mydomain.queue3")
queue.async {
    let imageURL: URL = URL(string: "https://www.brightedge.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Google-Secure-Search_SEL.jpg")!
    guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL) else {
        return
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
}
```

or replace the first `DispatchQueue` with `URLSession.dataTask`

```
let imageURL: URL = URL(string: "https://www.brightedge.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Google-Secure-Search_SEL.jpg")!

(URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)).dataTask(with: imageURL, completionHandler: { (imageData, response, error) in

    if let data = imageData {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}).resume()
```